# How to build xml document from grep output

Tags: grep, find, printing, xml

I want to transform result of `find | grep` operation to a structured XML document with file entries containing filename, number of occurrences, line number and line content. Does linux provide any tool to format the output as such or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: Never worked on `XML`, but you can give a try to `rst2xml` binary. It will convert restructured text into Docutils-native XML files.

Comment: use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell/15461774#15461774

Comment: On second thought, I'm a little confused by the relationship between the problem statement and the `find | grep` command. This command wouldn't include the kind of metadata that you're looking for, would it? Do you maybe mean that you want to parse the output of `grep -r` instead of `find | grep`?

Comment: @Rahul Does xmlstarlet actually help with this? I've used it a little bit, but not for anything like what it sounds like is being asked for here.

Answer (score 0):

So I took a crack at this with Python and I think I've come up with a simple script that does what you want. Here it is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""pathlist2xml.py

Takes a list of file-system paths and
generates an XML representation of the
corresponding file-system hierarchy.
"""

import sys
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, fromstring, tostring, XMLParser
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape
from os.path import join, isdir
from posix import lstat
import fileinput

def insert_path(xmlroot, path):
    """Updates an XML element `xmlroot` and adds the
    child elements that represent the path `path`."""

    # Initialize a node cursor to start at the root node
    xmlcursor = xmlroot

    # Keep track of the relative path
    fullpath = ''

    # Iterate through the components of the path
    for path_component in path.split('/'):

        # Update the path
        fullpath = join(fullpath, path_component)

        # UTF and XML encode the strings
        fullpath_encoded = escape(fullpath.encode('string-escape'))
        path_component_encoded = escape(path_component.encode('string-escape'))

        # Check to see if the component if already represented by a node
        xmlnodes = xmlcursor.xpath("./*[@name='%s']" % path_component_encoded)

        # If the node exists, update the cursor
        if xmlnodes:
            xmlcursor = xmlnodes[0]

        # If the node doesn't exists, create it
        else:

            # Create the node
            if isdir(fullpath):
                xmlcursor = SubElement(xmlcursor, "directory")
            else:
                xmlcursor = SubElement(xmlcursor, "file")

            # (Optional) Add some file-attributes
            # xmlcursor.set('name', path_component)
            xmlcursor.set('name', path_component_encoded)
            xmlcursor.set('path', fullpath_encoded)
            xmlcursor.set('inode', str(lstat(fullpath).st_ino))

    # Return the modified root element (for convenience - not necessary)
    return(xmlroot)

def paths_to_xml(pathlist):
    """ Takes a list of file-system paths and generates an XML
    representation of the corresponding file-system hierarchy.
    """

    xmlroot = Element('root')

    for path in pathlist:
        insert_path(xmlroot, path.strip().strip('/'))

    return(xmlroot)

# Read a list of file paths standard input or from a list of files
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Get the XML document
    xmlroot = paths_to_xml(fileinput.input())

    # Display the generated XML document
    print(tostring(xmlroot, pretty_print=True))
```

And here's a little example session illustrating how it might work in practice. First I created some directories and files:

```bsh
mkdir -p /tmp/xmltest
cd /tmp/xmltest
touch file1
touch file2
mkdir dir1
touch dir1/file3
touch dir1/file4
mkdir dir2
mkdir dir2/dir3
touch dir2/dir3/file5
```

Here's what this subhierarchy looks like with `tree`:

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file3
│   └── file4
├── dir2
│   └── dir3
│       └── file5
├── file1
└── file2
```

And here is an example of how you might call the script with output from just `find`:

```bsh
find . | pathlist2xml.py
```

And here is the XML output that was generated:

```
<root>
  <directory name="." path="." inode="3587802">
    <directory name="dir1" path="./dir1" inode="3587817">
      <file name="file3" path="./dir1/file3" inode="3587818"/>
      <file name="file4" path="./dir1/file4" inode="3587819"/>
    </directory>
    <directory name="dir2" path="./dir2" inode="3587820">
      <directory name="dir3" path="./dir2/dir3" inode="3587821">
        <file name="file5" path="./dir2/dir3/file5" inode="3587822"/>
      </directory>
    </directory>
    <file name="file1" path="./file1" inode="3587815"/>
    <file name="file2" path="./file2" inode="3587816"/>
  </directory>
</root>
```

And here is a second example combining `find` with `grep`:

```bsh
find . | grep dir2 | pathlist2xml.py
```

And here is the output from this second example:

```
<root>
  <directory name="." path="." inode="3587802">
    <directory name="dir2" path="./dir2" inode="3587820">
      <directory name="dir3" path="./dir2/dir3" inode="3587821">
        <file name="file5" path="./dir2/dir3/file5" inode="3587822"/>
      </directory>
    </directory>
  </directory>
</root>
```